# Firebase additionalUserInfo.isNewUser is always return false

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I use ionic 4 with firebase/angularfire2 and authenticate with `signinwithemeailandpassword()` method so I need to check the first time that user login after registration so I found that firebase gives that option with `isNewUser`

So when creating an account with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` the isNewUser is `equal` to `true` as it should or normal! But when login in with `signinwithemeailandpassword()` always returns false whatever is it the first time to login or not!

This the code for the login method:

```
 async login(form: NgForm) {

// checking if login is valid
if (form.invalid)
  return this.statusMessage.message('Validation error!');

console.log(this.user);

try {

  const results = await this._afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email, this.user.password).then(
    user => console.log(user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser)

  );
  // console.log(results);

} catch (error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case "auth/user-not-found":
      this.statusMessage.message("Your email address is wrong! please try again");
      break;

    case "auth/invalid-email":
      this.statusMessage.message("You have enterd invalid email address");
      break;

    case "auth/wrong-password":
      this.statusMessage.message('Password you have enterd is wrong');
      break;

    default:
      console.dir(error);
      this.statusMessage.message('Something wen wrong! please try again later');
      break;
  }

}
```

the signup code:

```
async register(form: NgForm) {

    // checking for form validation
    if (form.invalid) return this.statusMessage.message('Validation error!');

    console.log(this.user);

    try {
      await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.email, this.user.password).then(
        user => console.log(user)

      );
    } catch (error) {
      this.statusMessage.message('Somthing went wrong!, please try again later.');
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: some more code please

Comment: @ShashankVivek What more you need? I have updated the question with the registering method I have used too!

Comment: The response from `user.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` is always returns false after login in whatever is first time or not that's my problem!

Comment: *firebaser here* As far as I can see [the `isNewUser` value comes straight from the server](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/6b53e0058483c9002d2fe56119f86fc9fb96b56c/packages/auth/src/authuser.js#L1335), so it shouldn't be possible to get a wrong value there. Can you set up a quick, minimal repro (preferably with only the JavaScript SDK, no other frameworks) on a site like JSBin, so that I can share it with the team?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen From what I have understood that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method after I get call it it's signed in the user as well! so Future signings won't consider the user new anymore.

which kind weird to me! that for using isNewUser I have to get the user redirected to his profile after signup! without manual login again!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's false because its only true the first time they sign in. When you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` the client is logged in as that user. Future signins won't consider the user new anymore.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword):

> On successful creation of the user account, this user will also be signed in to your application.

The only time that `isNewUser` would be true with a normal login is if you made the account in the Firebase console or using the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: So how to avoid this! 

I need to make the user signup then redirect to the login page when he signs in a redirect to the profile page if it's first time logged in else home page!

Comment: @heshamshawky Just redirect them when they create their account, they'll already be signed in, there is no need to make them sign in after they just signed up.

Comment: Great answer Michael! I'd completely missed that the problem was on a subsequent sign-in. @heshamshawky: the typical way to handle is to detect if you have a completely profile for the user once they sign in. If you don't have a complete profile, you redirect them to the "complete your profile" page, otherwise you redirect to your main activity.